# Mercurial gives "invalid pattern" error for simple GLOB syntax

Tags: regex, version-control, unicode, mercurial, hgignore

I have the following in my `.hgignore` file:

```
syntax: glob
obj/*
bin/*
*.suo
*.user
*.ncb
```

If I comment out the `*.` filters, the filtering works fine filtering out the files in the `bin` and `obj` folder, however, if I keep those filters in I receive the following error:

```
abort: c:\temp\.hgignore: invalid pattern (relre): *.suo
```

Note:  The file is encoded in UTF-8

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error message from Mercurial tells us that your `syntax: glob` line is not read by Mercurial. Patterns in ignore files default to regular expressions, and `*.suo` is indeed an invalid regular expression (a regex cannot start with `*`).

Since this is on Windows, and since the file is UTF-8 encoded, then the only reasonable explanation is that there is somehthing that makes Mercurial ignore the `syntax: glob` line. An [**UTF-8 BOM**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) is such a "something"! A byte order mark is a small signature inserted into UTF-16 encoded files to signal the byte order of the file. This is not needed or recommended for UTF-8 encoded files, but Windows editors have a tendency to insert them anyway.

To fix this, please open the file in Notepad and choose "Save As". Then pick ANSI as the encoding. Your `.hgignore` file is pure ASCII, so this will effective be the same as UTF-8 without a BOM.

Comment: I have my Mercurial.ini file in my user folder (i.e. C:\users\ME).  In that folder under the [ui] heading i have my username defined.  So you're saying that in that same file, adding syntax: glob will help?  (Just verifying, because I can't test it until later tonight)

Comment: I just re-read your question more carefully and came up with a better explanation. You only need to re-save your `.hgignore` file.

Comment: I didn't get to try it last night, but I'm excited to try it tonight!

Comment: @contactmatt: any news about this issue? I'm curious to hear if I guessed correctly in my answer :-)

Comment: Thanks alot @Martin !  I opened the file in Notepad++, saved the file as an ANSI file, and tested to see if it ignored those files and it does.  Great insight about the UTF-8 format!

Comment: Great, I'm glad to hear that we figure it out!

Answer (score 3):

To ignore the complete `bin` and `obj` folders, you don't need the `/*` behind them.

My default `.hgignore` file for Visual Studio projects looks like this:

```
syntax: glob
bin
obj
*.suo
*.user
```

Answer (score 1):

mercurial is somehow not interpreting the line **syntax: glob** because of the BOM (Byte-Order-Mark inserted right in front of the file, on windows x86-x64 running on Intel platform uses little endian) on windows platform you have to save the file as ASCII as contactmatt has advised.

Interestingly you can see the 2 byte BOM (Byte-Order-Mark) in hex view of the file saved on windows platform using utf-8 encoding

[image]

Now try to save this file using notepad in ASCII encoding and you would see that Byte-Order-Mark would be removed and mercurial would stop complaining about it. Attaching hex view after saving the file in ASCII.

[image]